# Перегрузка оператора присваивания одного объекта с другим

Tags: python

Как переопределить оператор присваивания, что бы значения одного объекта присваивались другому, например:

```
class Obj1():
  def __init__(self, x, y):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y

class Obj2():
  def __init__(self, x, y, z):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.z = z
  
a = Obj1(1,2)
b = Obj2(0, 0, 0)
b = a 
# в b должны быть значения 1, 2, 0
```

Comment: Создайте класс, определите в нём свой метод `__add__`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы не можете переопределить присваивание. Но можно сделать как-то так - обновить одноименные свойства значениями из другого объекта, если я правильно понял ваш замысел

```
class Obj:
    def replace(self, x):
        for name in x.__dict__:
            value = getattr(x, name)
            if not name.startswith('__') \   # не приватное свойство
               and hasattr(self, name):      # есть в текущем объекте
                setattr(self, name, value)


class Obj1(Obj):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y


class Obj2(Obj):
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z


a = Obj1(1, 2)
b = Obj2(0, 0, 0)
b.replace(a)
print(b.x, b.y, b.z)  # 1 2 0
```

Comment: Спасибо! Примерно это и надо

Answer (score 1):

Напрямую через оператор присваивания - нельзя. Но можно сделать "финт ушами". Например, организовать это через оператор сдвига. :)

```
class Obj1():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

class Obj2():
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z
    
    def __ilshift__(self, other):
        if hasattr(other, 'x'): self.x = other.x
        if hasattr(other, 'y'): self.y = other.y
        return self

a = Obj1(1,2)
b = Obj2(0, 0, 0)
print("До", b.x, b.y, b.z)
b <<= a 
# в b должны быть значения 1, 2, 0
print("После", b.x, b.y, b.z)
```

```
До 0 0 0
После 1 2 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понял, питонический вариант сделать это примерно такой:

```
class Obj2():
  def __init__(self, x, y, z):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.z = z

  def fromObj1(obj1):
    return Obj2(obj1.x, obj1.y, 0)

a = Obj1(1,2)
b = Obj2.fromObj1(a)
```

Само присваивание насколько я понимаю подменить нельзя, хотя я, конечно, могу и ошибаться.

Comment: Спасибо! Но там не всегда 0 может быть

Comment: @helldrg А, понятно. Я просто не совсем понял в чём задумка была